How to correctly sort in Excel with by custom list?
I have a list I would like to sort by. But I think the list must be sorted? My list is this:
Pu, Tsu, ʢu, Wu, Bi, Tzi, Ri, Yi, Do, So, Mo, Who, Ta, Za, Rra, ɲa

My entries are values such as:
PuDo, PuZa, BiSoTa, PuBi, SoSo, TziRra

Which if sorted correctly would look like:
PuBi, PuDo, PuZa, BiSoTa, TziRra, SoSo

But what I get from Excel is:
BiSoTa, PuDo, PuZa, SoSo, TziRra, PuBi


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In my testing with custom lists (with your list and the built-in ones), entries need to match exactly to the items in it to be sorted accordingly.
Not sure whether you're interested in alternatives, but here's quick suggestion using Excel for Microsoft 365:

Split the entries by sort-by list
Use the index of these split entries in the sort-by list with SORTBY
This is quick, 'crude' solution, limited to three 'splits'
Enter in a cell where you want the result (C1 in the screenshot)

=LET(
    sort_by, TRIM(
        TEXTSPLIT("Pu, Tsu, ʢu, Wu, Bi, Tzi, Ri, Yi, Do, So, Mo, Who, Ta, Za, Rra, ɲa", ",")
    ),
    entries, A1:A6,
    match_in_sortby, LAMBDA(str,
        IFNA(INDEX(sort_by, XMATCH(TRUE, FIND(sort_by, str) = 1)), "")
    ),
    index_in_sortby, LAMBDA(lst, IFNA(XMATCH(lst, sort_by), ROWS(entries) + 1)),
    list_1, MAP(entries, match_in_sortby),
    list_2, MAP(SUBSTITUTE(entries, list_1, "", 1), match_in_sortby),
    list_3, MAP(SUBSTITUTE(entries, list_1 & list_2, "", 1), match_in_sortby),
    SORTBY(
        entries,
        index_in_sortby(list_1),
        ,
        index_in_sortby(list_2),
        ,
        index_in_sortby(list_3),
        
    )
)

Result from SORTBY


So, a bit of a verbose solution, one that even required a few newer features within Excel. Formula in D1:
=SORTBY(C1:C6,BYROW(TEXT(IFNA(XMATCH(DROP(REDUCE("",REGEXREPLACE(C1:C6,"\p{Ll}\K\p{Lu}","|$0"),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(y,"|")))),1),A1:A16),),"00"),CONCAT))

This is now able to accept much larger strings as input to. Try any combination if you will to test this (and please get back to me if it's incorrect).
